# Why is EF4.1 CodeFirst is creating a database even without a `Database.SetInitializer<>()` call?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have commented out all calls to `Database.SetInitializer<>()` in my EF Code First application.  However, even without any explicit calls to create the database, my Asp.net MVC application is still creating a database.  I have several reasons why this is an issue:

1) I don't like the fact that EF is creating a new database without me telling it to.

2) It keeps trying to create (or update) the database on my webhost (even though the database already exists), and thus I am getting permission denied exceptions.

Does anyone have any insight why this seems totally out of my control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CTP 5 the solution was

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

I think this didn't change in EF 4.1. If you comment the call out it defaults to `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`.

Comment: That worked, Thanks!  That's annoying that I have to do that though.